# Google Analytics UTM Codes in Conversions Goals

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 websites. (Site A and SIte B)

I am passing UTM codes From Site A to Site B page. (Site A page 1 to Site B page 2) Site A with UTM tracking info - https://www.SiteA.com/?utm_source=MYsource&utm_medium=MY_web&utm_campaign=MY_Testing

Destination - https://www.SiteB.com/registernow.aspx

I can see my UTM tracking info (utm_medium,utm_source,utm_campaign) on RealTime Data (on 'Traffic Sources',Conversions) in real-time. All required information are there.

I can see my UTM tracking info (utm_medium,utm_source,utm_campaign) on Acquisition Data (on 'Campaigns',Conversions). Everything that I need is there too.

But I can not see my UTM tracking info on Conversions --> Goals. (I have set up the Goal and the Goal name and the UTM data are tracking on 'RealTime Data' and 'Acquisition Data'. But not on Goals. I am trying this for a week now and checking after 24 hours. But the tracking info is not there. I think I can see source/medium as (direct) / (none).)

I just added the UTM to site B to test. (Not through Site A. The Site B itself with adding UTM codes in the URL) If we open the Goal URL just manually on Site B through an email or through a browser, then it is tracking on 'Conversions --> Goals' with the UTM tracking code.

The problem is when we pass UTM through Site A.

I tried these 2 examples. https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/transfer-utm-parameters-google-tag-manager/ https://www.analyticsmania.com/other-posts/transfer-utms-from-one-page-to-another-with-gtm-version-1/

I am not sure where I have missed it.

I want to get my UTM tracking info to 'Conversions --> Goals' when we pass it through Site A page 1 to Site B page 2.

Please, can you help me to sort this issue out? I really appreciate it if you can support me. It has been more than10 days since to figure out the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by what you have described.

Do you have cross-domain tracking set up between siteA and siteB?

I'm guessing probably not, hence why the UTM parameters are being used.

To track a goal you would set up your goal in siteB's GA eg a destination URL for whatever the landing page URL is (without the UTM parameters) and then look at the Aquisition > Campaigns report or the Aquisition > All Traffic reports to see goal conversions for your particular UTMs

Or look at the SiteB landing pages report and add a Secondary Dimension for source/medium that matches your UTM parameters

Alternatively, create a segment that matches your UTM source/medium

Provided the UTMs aren't being stripped when ppl land on siteB, then your reporting for siteB should be fine without any fancy setup